# where is meta super user on the list of stack exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, meta, superuser

https://stackexchange.com/users/276507/neubert?tab=accounts

I see meta stack over flow but not meta super user (which I just joined / posted to).

One thing that's weird about meta super user...  my reputation is the same there as it is on the regular super user. That makes me think that maybe only meta stack overflow is it's own actual stack exchange site. But if that's the case then why aren't my badges being shared as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meta Stack Overflow covers *the entire stack exchange network* and because of this it's a little different.

- MSO has it's own reputation system, so you get rep for upvotes and lose rep for downvotes.
- MSO is its *own* site; whereas all the other meta sites are sub-sites of their respective mother sites.  Because of this you don't need to create an account to participate in your site's meta (unlike MSO), and thus there isn't an account listed on the accounts page.

See the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) for more information about MSO and meta sites in general.  Specifically:

[Are upvotes and downvotes different on meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

[Why was my feature/bug declined or closed without explanation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#declined-closed)

Answer (score 8):

Meta Stack Overflow is... special. It covers the dual task of being the Meta site for Stack Overflow *and* for the entire Stack Exchange network.

The Meta sites for all the other sites are not separate. You cannot gain reputation there, they are an integral part of the main site they belong with, your account on such a *normal* meta site is not separate either.

As such, meta.superuser.com is not listed separately in the account list. Neither is meta.serverfault.com, nor are meta.programmers.stackexchange.com, meta.judaism.stackexchange.com, meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com, meta.rpg.stackexchange.com, etc. etc.